# Моделирование данных в MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, javascript, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь в выборе структуры базы данных.

Сначала я делал так: у меня было **несколько** коллекций, в которых были документы с тремя полями каждый. Каждая коллекция - это изучаемая дисциплина (Физика, Математика и т.д.). Каждый документ - это объект состоящий из трех полей: вопрос, ответ и тип вопроса. Поиск должен производится по вопросу.

Но в таком случае я не могу указать коллекции какие-то свойства (или могу?). Я решил попробовать записать все предметы в **одну** коллецию, а ответы сделать полями документа. Но в таком случае я не знаю как производить поиск по вопросам.

Так же, я прочитал про третий способ - использование ***DBRef***. То есть я могу создать коллецию со всеми предметами, которые будут являтся документами и будут иметь какие-то свойства.Затем создать коллеции для каждого предмета и сделать ссылки на них в коллекции с предметами.

**Внимание вопрос:** *зачем мне все это?* На самом деле вот он: как мне лучше организовать данные? Нужна упорядоченность по предмету, то есть нужно точно знать из какой дисциплины это вопрос. Также интересно какой способ более эффективный в плане поиска.

Comment: dbref это определенно не лучшее решение вашего вопроса, храните данные в формате:

    {
       id : ...,
       // more data here
    }

Когда нужна инфа по объекту - вытаскиваем из отдельной коллекции по id (если перенести на реляционную БД, то, по сути, делаем join), это самое простое решение, но, справедливости ради, не единственное.

Answer (score 2):

очень кучеряво написано и не все понятно, но ссылаться на что-то из чего-то - это атавизм из SQL. Нужно понять, что документ в Mongo может хранить таги и сразу же описание к ним и все что тебе нужно и одной коллекции будет вполне достаточно.

```
{ vopros: "Скорость Светы в вакууме",
  otvet: "6 км/ч",
  tip_voprose: "каверзный",
  predmet: "физика"
}
```

А дальше читаем [мануал к монге](http://jsman.ru/mongo-book/) и играем с **db.find()**